# Searching in one file and replacing it in another file

Tags: sed, grep, replace

I am searching a substring in one file and replacing it with every occurrence of word "PASSWORD" in another file. Let say I have file1 with content:

```
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => {"expression" => "${ENC::initial-resolver:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}"}
}
```

and another file2 with content:

```
/subsystem=elytron/key-store=fipsKS:add(path=/home/jboss/jboss/jboss-eap-7.4/ssl/certstore.bcfks,type=BCFKS,credential-reference={clear-text=PASSWORD}
```

I like to capture `"${ENC::initial-resolver:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}"` from file1
and replace it with 'PASSWORD' in file2.

I am guessing I can do it using grep and sed,
but not sure how and would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: (1) Please use example text that is no more than 80 to 90 characters per line, so it can be viewed without horizontal scrolling.  (2) Please try harder to explain what you want — I don’t understand what you’re saying — **and** show an example of the result that you want. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) Please clarify: when you say `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`, do you mean (a) `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`, (b) a string of 32 characters that I know, but I’m not telling you, because it’s secret, (c) a string of 32 characters that I don’t know in advance, or (d) a string of characters that I don’t know in advance, and I don’t even know how long it will be? … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.